# Remove Post Excerpt for Specific Page

Tags: php, wordpress

for my site I have set post excerpt length using a function:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
function my_excerpt_length($len) { return 125; }
```

This sets post excerpt length universally across the site.  However, for a specific page ID, Id like to display full length of the post.

My thought is to include and elseif similar to:

```
function my_excerpt_length($len) { 
    if (is_page(39370)) {
        return 1000; 
    } else {
        return 125;
    }
}
```

I am thinking this code will set the excerpt length for this specific page long enough that the full post should show, but is there another way to accomplish this that would ensure the full post is displayed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `get_the_excerpt()` filter to replace the excerpt with the content:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'so20668477_get_the_excerpt', 10, 1 );
function so20668477_get_the_excerpt( $excerpt )
{
    if( is_page( 39370 ) )
        $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );

    return $excerpt;
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, adding this new function to my child theme, and it did bricked my page.  Not sure if I am missing something.  Also, what do the 10, 1 represent?

Comment: Should work. Turn on `WP_DEBUG` and check what error you're getting. `10` is the filter priority, `1` is the n° of arguments passed, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter#Parameters

Comment: yes, I have to setup dev environment today, was working directly on the live site, and it is getting a good amount of traffic.  Thanks for help, I will keep working with the recommendations posted in this thread.  This thread will show you more detail of how I implemented the code you sent over:  http://bit.ly/1bf6v4f

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
is_page( 'page' );
```

where `'page'` is the post title